# How to take random no of inputs in n lines in python

Tags: python, random, input

Hey I want to take random no of inputs in `n` lines in python . like --

```
line1-   1 2 3 4
line2-   1
line3-   4 5 6
.
.
.
upto n lines
```

Comment: Ummm, okay? What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: If you're getting user's input, you can use `input()` and if reading from file use `readline()`. Then parse each line and find each value from each line.

Comment: i am getting user input like                         for i in range (n):    t,x,y=map(int,input().split())                                  and in between i just want to get t(not x and y) so how can i solve that issue